# Kerberos SSO browser integration?

Tags: kerberos, openldap, single-sign-on

I'm installing a bunch of web apps for the office, and one of the wants would be Kerberos-managed SSO.

Now, I have found [some](https://serverfault.com/questions/101462/how-to-setup-apache-redirect-or-custom-401-document-on-kerberos-sso-login-failure) [information](https://serverfault.com/questions/69354/seamless-sso-with-kerberos-ie-firefox-ldap-active-directory) on the matter, and I wondered, what browsers integrate Kerberos SSO?

Of course I could just use the underlying web app to authenticate in case of lack of Kerberos capability, which is exactly the plan, but I'd like to know which browsers would work for that, so I can plan ahead and decide if it's even worth it to do that, which I believe it would considering that one of the web apps I'm implementing will be an ERP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox natively supports GSSAPI authentication. See [here](http://grolmsnet.de/kerbtut/firefox.html) for more information.

Comment: chrome can be configured to do GSSAPI authentication as well:

http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution that will work across the systems you are using, mod_auth_krb5 and firefox will work for internal access, however I recommend using a slightly different solution: WebAuth from Stanford. It can use Kerberos + GSSAPI to login, but can will also allow browsers that don't support GSSAPI negotiation and let them login and have a SSO experiance as well:

http://webauth.stanford.edu/

Comment: Of course time has passed since this post and the referred tool is no longer a viable choice.